# Extracting data from Mailchimp API v3

Tags: curl, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Is there a  way for me to get(through Mailchimp API) the list of all the people who opened a particular campaign and the list of all the people who clicked on a particular campaign, etc ?? I want the required data campaign-wise because we send about 5 campaigns everyday and we want to know which people are clicking or opening what type of campaign. Could anyone please help me for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Get email activity](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/reports/email-activity/#read-get_reports_campaign_id_email_activity)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just wanted to ask that I am trying to get cick-details using this link- http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/reports/click-details/. But the problem is that I cannot get the list of members who clicked on a specific campaign, this link gives me the list of people who clicked on different urls of a particular campaign. I want the entire thing in one json file. How do I do it ? thanks for your help.

Comment: I still think you are looking for the endpoint I linked in my answer. It takes a campaign id, and returns among other things a list of members that opened the campaign, and which links they clicked.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked, I also wanted to ask you that, I cannot extract email-activity of more than 5000 people for a particular campaign using Mailchimp API v3 through R or cURL. Is there a limit for the same or is there a better way to extract data of more than 5000 people for a campaign through API ? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did as you said, but using Batch Operations I am trying to retrieve email-activity of 200000 people, it nearly took me 4 hours. Is there a faster way to do it ?

Comment: This is my batch operation ("campaign_id" is the id of the particular campaign with 200000 people in it, so can it be faster than this ?)- {"operations": [ { "method": "GET", "path": "/reports/"campaign_id"/email-activity", "operation_id" : "3" } ] }

Comment: I don't think you can get it any faster. You can try the following though. A batch call with more operations using count and offset to split the 200000 into smaller chunks. Or the same approach with multiple parallel normal get requests, using count and offset to split it into smaller chunks

Comment: How to GET 3 fields from email-activity of 200,000 people through BATCH operations ? Thank you.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by GET 3 fields

Comment: I mean that I want to GET email_address, campaign_id and email_id(which are present in email-activity along with many other things) of all the people using BATCH operations. Thank you.

Comment: I am trying to GET information(specific fields from email-activity), how should I do it in Batch GET requests in Mailchimp api v3? This is my code -

{
"operations": [
  {
    "method": "GET", 
    "path": "/reports/campaign_id/email-activity",
   "operation_id" : "123"
  }
]
}
With the above code, the entire email-activity is extracted, I only need few fields from email-activity like "email_address" and "campaign_id". How do I do it using BATCH GET request using Mailchimp API v3? Thank you

Comment: I am not able to parse locally stored JSON file which looks something like this-

[{"status_code":200,"operation_id":"13-10","response":"{\"emails\":[{\"campaign_id\":\"1111111\",\"email_address\":\"1111@111\",\"activity\":[]},{\"campaign_id\":\"22222\",\"email_address\":\"2222@2222\",\"activity\":[]}}}] As you can see this - '\'(backslash)is present everywhere, and I am unable to parse it. Could anyone please help. Thank you.